# How can a draw a circle in java pixel by pixel using a graphical app?

Tags: java, applet, draw, geometry

The applet used is like the first quadrant of a Cartisian Plane with the domain and range (0, 200). My assignment is to draw a house and a sun in this applet.
I am trying to draw the circle for the sun.  I really have no idea where to start.  We are learning about for loops and nested loops so it probably pertains to that. We haven't got to arrays and general functions like draw.circle do not exist for this applet.  If it helps, here is how I drew my roof for the house (two right triangles):  Notice it is drawn pixel by pixel.  I suspect my teacher wants the same kind of thing for the circle.

```
//roof
//left side
double starty = 100;
for(double x = 16; x <= 63; x++){
        for(int y = 100; y <= starty; y++){
               img.set(x, y, JRaster.purple);
        }
starty += 1;
}

//right side
double startx = 110;
for(int y = 100; y <= 147; y++){
       for(double x = 63; x <= startx; x++){
               img.set(x , y, JRaster.purple);
       }
startx -= 1;
}
```

Comment: I guess I should rephrase: PLEASE READ ALL. Some people skim over the question and do not answer accordingly.   I explain some things that could potentially be ignored.

Comment: @ Shaelana: Then deal with it if and when it happens. Again, all that preface does is make people who could help you move on to something else. It *doesn't* make someone who skims not skim.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Alright, alright. You make a good point. I'll edit it.

Comment: A circle a set of curves draw through at least 4 main points, you could take a look at [this](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lambert/splines/) for some basic examples.

Comment: A better solution might be to take advantage of the [2D Graphics API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) directly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would draw the north-east quarter of a circle, pixel by pixel.  You can just repeat this with slight variations for the other three quarters.  No trigonometry required!

- Start by drawing the eastern most point of the circle.  Then you'll draw more pixels, moving northwards and westwards, until you get to the northern most point of the circle.
- Calculate the distance of the point you've just drawn from the centre.  If it's more than the radius, then your next pixel will be one to the left, otherwise, your next pixel will be the one above.
- Repeat the previous step till you get to the northern most point.

Post a comment if you get stuck, with converting this to Java, or with adjusting it for the other three quarters of the circle.

Comment: Wouldn't this give me a rhombus or something?  I don't know how the curve would be implemented for this code without trig although it would be nice

Comment: No, no, you have misunderstood.  You work out, pixel by pixel, whether you should be going UP or LEFT.  You'll get a nice curve with an even consistency, and it will run WAY faster than working out a `sin` and a `cos` for every point of the circle.  To work out whether to go up or left, you just compare `(x - centreX) * (x - centreX) + (y - centreY) * (y - centreY)` with `radiusSquared`.  Trust me, you'll get a nice quarter circle.

Comment: Oh I see! That's really awesome! Would it be the same if I were going, say either down or right?

Comment: Sure.  So when you draw the south-west quarter, you might start at the western-most point, and work downwards and rightwards until you reach the southern-most point.

Comment: Cool. Thank you so much.  I wonder if I'll get extra credit for having a faster code than everyone else :P

Comment: :D  - Don't know about the extra credit.  Hey, I just realised, although this draws the outline of a circle, you might have wanted a solid circle.  Were you wanting a solid circle?  If so, there are a couple of changes you'll want to make to this method.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you code, but you should remember how a circle is made. Going from theta=0 to theta=2*pi, the circle is traced by `x=cos x`, `y=sin x`.

So, using a for loop that increments a double(here called theta) by something like 0.01 until 2*pi(`2*Math.PI` or roughly 6.28) plot off `Math.cos(theta), Math.sin(theta)`.

Comment: @ShaelanaPass Thanks. If this helped please mark the checkmark next to the answer when you can.